# How do you debug azure function deployments?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm new to azure and I'm finding it pretty frustrating to deploy my azure functions to azure using the cli. I'm running commands similar to this:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g my-resource-group -n my-function-app --src ./functions.zip
```

It's working now bit I had a lot of issues at first. For example I was using `tar` to zip up the functions and azure doesn't like that. Another time I zipped up the root directory from the parent instead of zipping up the everything from inside the root directory. Azure doesn't like that.

That's all fine but I when I made these mistakes azure didn't give me any errors, it just silently failed and I had to make guesses about what I was doing wrong. When I do a function upload that doesn't work how can I get more information about what went wrong?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to zip the functions? add --debug flag to your command

Comment: That's how the [deployment method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) I mentioned works. It takes a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you debug azure function deployments?

**`One of the way`** to check is by using **`--debug`**  while deploying the Azure Function App (Zip) and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "resourcegrpname" -n "funcappname"  --src "FunctionApp51.zip" --debug
```

[image]

[image]

**`Second way`** is by clicking on **`Advanced tools`**, and then click on **`Go`** :

[image]

then click on debug console, then on powershell then:

[image]

**`Logs:`**

[image]

**`Third Way:`** using below command and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-deployment-list):

```
az webapp log deployment list -n "funcappname" -g "resourcegrpname"
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I tried the `--debug` flag. It outputs a giant wall of text so it's hard to tell but it didn't seem to indicate any problems. I don't have an Advanced Tools option or even a Development Tools section under my function app. How did you get access to that?

Comment: It will be present in Azure Portal and it is available for everyone and all plans, try to refresh and check again

Comment: You're seeing that under the function app?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing this inside the function app service